# Looking for RPGs without character-classes

Tags: game-recommendation, class

Right now I'm playing Shadowrun4, I know that there don't exist classes which restrict your character developement.
Are there any other P&P RPGs out there, which also don't have classes?

That means particularly: 
I don't want ANY classes at all. The RPG should be for up to 5 players (plus GM). 
I don't want something like a tabletop: A plain P&P RPG where nothing else but your character stats and probably a set of dices is needed.

The genre is not important. Sci-Fi, Fantasy, anything will do. I should probably say that I'm also interested in "bigger" RPGs with a good and well-elaborated background story.

Comment: The answer to this is trivially "yes," and any more in-depth answer would turn into an unending list of literally *hundreds* of different systems. If you're looking for a game recommendation, we'll need more specific criteria to work with.  How many players and what session/campaign length; what genre or tone; do you want miniatures on a grid or theatre of the mind; what features of character development *are* you looking for; and so forth. Tell us what you *do* want as well as what you don't, so we can make useful suggestions. If you'd just like to chat about the topic, come join the [chat].

Comment: Are you looking for a completely classless system or is system with templates going to be okay? Is it that you do not want **any classes at all** (e.i. warrior learns magic freely) or just **no classes that restrict character development** (warrior can learn magic but it's harder for him than for a mage)? Please clarify

Comment: Hundreds? Oh well, I think I'm probably not that deep in roleplaying games ;) I don't want ANY classes at all. It should be for up to 5 players (plus GM). [Miniatures on a grid or theatre of mind] - if I get that right, I don't want something like a tabletop? A plain P&P RPG where nothing else but your character stats and probably a set of dices is needed. The genre is not important. Sci-Fi, Fantasy, anything will do. I should probably say that I'm also interested in "bigger" RPGs with a good and deep background story

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is a google search for "classless RPGs" or similar. There are a lot of systems out there, GURPS, Paranoia and Exalted to list a few. Unfortunatly, this is just too broad a question to answer reasonably.

Comment: @Ferox you should add those restrictions into your question, such as demanding a good deep pre-written backstory, and also expand on what you mean by not being a tabletop, but also being ok with miniatures on a grid.

Comment: @Ferox We've put your question temporarily on hold until we can focus it better. It's not punishment, just a temporary hold until we can make sure the question generates *good*, *relevant* answers.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. Asking is far more complicated than reading questions from other people ;)

Comment: @Ferox It's a good start, but it's still a very broad question. I can easily think of several answers that fit thebill (*Ars Magica*, *Dresden Files*, and others) none of which will be the *correct* one, which doesn't really fit in well with Stack Exchange's "concrete answers to concrete questions" goal.

Comment: @Ferox what other restrictions can you think of? Do you care about if the game is free or not? If it has a large online community? Artwork? Do you care if it uses special dice unique to the game , or normal d6s?

Comment: This question seems related:  http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/are-there-any-rpgs-settings-where-a-characters-class-is-not-chosen-but-earned

Comment: @Ferox Elaborating on lisardggY's comment, here are a few question that could help you tell us what you're looking for: Do you need one of the players to be the game master or are masterless games ok? Do you want it to focus on combat, character development (this usually does not work well with "deep, pre-written backstories", since players tend to cristallyze on those), creating a story togheter? Must it be a collaborative or a free-for-all game? Should it be able to manage long campaigns or just one-shots is ok? Setting/tech limitations might also be useful.

Comment: Think about your *actual problem* and then explain it to us.  Are you looking for a game like this to run (in which case I bet you/your players have a lot more specific requirements than "whatever")?  Or are you wanting to understand how character progression works without classes from a game design standpoint?

Comment: I just reviewed your edit and personally chose *not* to re-open this question based on that edit, so I wanted to give you some tips: we are not for idea-generating. It is a requirement of questions here that they conceivably have *One, True, Correct Answer*, so that people can vote on answers based on how well they meet the criteria set forth in the question. Because you have no requirements aside from having no classes, *all answers that include a system without classes are equally good*, and voting just becomes a popularity contest. We don't do popularity contests.

Comment: In short, we can't tell you what you want; you have to decide that for yourself. When you decide what you want, we can help you find the perfect system to satisfy those wants. But we can't just throw systems at you until something sticks.

Comment: More pointedly, *we* can't just throw systems at you until something sticks, because that's not what SE is designed to do well, but it's *perfectly fine* to want to have systems thrown at you. You just have to use a tool designed for that kind of discussion: forums. I suggest [RPG.net](http://forum.rpg.net/forumdisplay.php?3-Tabletop-Roleplaying-Open), since they really like this kind of system-throwing exercise and have a broad experience of the thousands of game systems out there.

Comment: Do note that something like 90% of RPGs - most of them except for the D&D's and other stuff made by TSR/WotC and other really old games (Palladium) don't have classes. Classes are actually unusual in game design but since D&D is what so many  have played it seems like it's the default.